# How to get 90%+ test accuracy on IMDB data?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I was trying to train a model using IMDB data. I am getting expected train accuracy about 96%+ but I am not satisfied with the test accuracy.Now my expectation is to get 90%+ test accuracy on test data. I tried by using several classifier but each time I am getting 84% to 89% accuracy on test data. Here I am going to include some classifiers I already tried. Most of the cases I tried some parameter tuning by increasing epoch or changing the optimizer. Now my concern is how can I increase the test accuracy to 90%+ .

Classifiers I tried so far:

First:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 32, input_length = max_words))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True)))
model.add(GlobalMaxPool1D())
model.add(Dense(20, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),epochs=10,batch_size=100)
```

Second:

```
    model = Sequential([
            Embedding(vocab_size, 32, input_length=max_words),
            Dropout(0.2),
            ZeroPadding1D(padding=1),
            Convolution1D(64, 5, activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.2),
            MaxPooling1D(),
            Flatten(),
            Dense(100, activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.2),
            Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
        ])
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),epochs=10,batch_size=100)
```

Comment: What is your target?  What makes you believe that you should be able to get 90% accuracy?

Comment: Can you share the training vs validation loss graph, so that we can check if its underfitting/overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

By checking on [State-of-the-art analysis on IMDB dataset](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/sentiment-analysis-on-imdb), I don't think you can get to ^90% with simple models like those you are using. However, you may try using pretrained embedding like [glove](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) instead of training your own embedding. Also, I found [this repo](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/master/demo/tune/keras_bert_classification_tpu.ipynb) have BERT implementation in keras, providing demo of IMBD classification, it is able to get ~99% acc.

Comment: BERT large reaches 95%. The best ML solution reaches 97%. There are lots of notebooks and examples that brag about 99% accuracy and in my experience they *all* were trained using test data. Here’s one snapshot of the current leaderboard: https://paperswithcode.com/sota/sentiment-analysis-on-imdb